# Проблема с созданием аналога SetLength на C++

Tags: c++, массивы, динамические-массивы, malloc, devc++

Пытаюсь сделать аналог SetLength (паскаль) в C++
Просто уже нет сил без такой же удобной вещи, но мой код почему-то не работает
Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <clocale>
using namespace std;

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

template <typename T>
void SetL(T * array, int newLen)
{
    int Len = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
    void *ptrArray;
    int LenCell = sizeof(array[0]);

    if (Len ==1 )
    {
        ptrArray= calloc(newLen,LenCell);
        if (ptrArray!=NULL)  
            {
                array=memcpy(ptrArray,array,sizeof(array));
            }
        }   

}

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    setlocale( LC_ALL,"Russian" );
    int n;
    cout<<"Äëèíó ìàññèâà a ââåäè\n";
    cin>>n;
    int a[n];
    SetL(a,n+5);
    cout<<sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Ошибка:

> 1)   In instantiation of 'void SetL(T*, int) [with T = int]':
>   2)   [Error] invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]

Среда разработки: Dev-C++

Comment: Что функция вообще должна делать?

Comment: И еще, вот так в C++ нельзя `cin>>n;int a[n];`

Answer (score 2):

Стандарт языка С++ не разрешает объявлять массивы переменной длины, как это имеет место в вашей программе

```
cin>>n;
int a[n];
```

Хотя некоторые компиляторы имеют собственные расширения языка, которые включают в себя возможность создавать массивы переменной длины, тем не менее лучше не пользоваться этими расширениями языка, так как код не будет удовлетворять стандарту С++, и тем самым будет не переносим и зависеть от конкретного компилятора и его настроек.

Кроме того массивы являются неизменяемыми `lvalue`, это означает, что вы не можете присвоить массиву другое значение. Так что ваш код в любом случае не имеет смысла.

В этой функции

```
template <typename T>
void SetL(T * array, int newLen)
```

параметр `array` является локальной переменной функции. Его изменение внутри функции никак не влияет на исходный аргумент, то есть на массив `a`.

Данное предложение

```
int Len = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
```

не вычисляет количество элементов в исходном массиве, как вы, по всей видимости, думаете. `array` - это указатель, имеющий объявление `T * array`, Указатели в общем случае имеют размер либо 4 байта, либо 8 байтов в зависимости от используемой платформы. Значение выражения `sizeof(array[0])` для данного вызова функции эквивалентно выражению `sizeof( int )` и также может быть равно либо 4 либо 8 байтам. То есть вы всегда будете получать значения для выражения `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])` либо 1 либо 2 независимо от того, сколько элементов имеет исходный массив, переданный в функцию в качестве аргумента.

Так как переменная `array` - это локальная переменна функции, которая прекратит свое существование после выхода из функции, то имеет место утечка памяти, так как адрес динамически выделенной памяти будет утерян, и память не будет освобождена.

Что касается сообщения об ошибке компилятора, то она относится к предложению

```
array=memcpy(ptrArray,array,sizeof(array));
```

Возвращаемое значение функции `memcpy` имеет тип `void *`, которое нельзя без явного приведения типов присвоить указателю типа `int *`, то есть переменной `array`.

Кроме того лучше использовать оператор `new` для выделения памяти в C++, чем стандартные функции C типа `malloc` или `calloc`.

Если вам нужны массивы переменной длины, то используйте стандартный класс `std::vector`, объявленный в заголовке `<vector>`.

Например,

```
std::vector<int> a( n );
//...
a.resize( n + 5 );
```